# Restrict available command options in AuCTeX

Tags: auctex

I'm using AuCTeX (v.11.89.6 with Emacs 25.1). I have no problems with it, just a small nuisance. Whenever I use `TeX-insert-macro` (C-c C-m) I get many options I never use. For instance, when I wish to insert the command `\enquote{...}`, I run `TeX-insert-macro` and start typing `enq`. The first option I get is `MakeHyphenQuote` and so I have to scroll down to select `enquote`.

[image]

To go around this issue, I used to edit the `csquotes.el` style file and remove `MakeHyphenQuote` from the list. However, each time AuCTeX updates itself, my file is removed and all customisation gets lost.

I also tried editing the `TeX-symbol-list` variable (which, according to `apropos-value`, seems to hold these commands), but couldn't make it to work.

So my question is whether I can remove `MakeHyphenQuote` (or any other command or environment) from the list used by AuCTeX for command insertion.

---

Update: just to make it clear, I'm using `ivy-mode`.

Comment: Strange, I don't get this behaviour (albeit on `GNU Emacs  24.3.1` and AUCTeX v.11.87). `TeX-insert-macro RET \enq TAB` will auto-complete to `\enquote` and a second `TAB` will pop up a completion menu that has (only) `\enquote` and `\enquote*`. To get `\hyphenquote(*)` (etc.), I need to start typing `\hyph` and `TAB` twice to get the auto completion menu.

Comment: I'm using `ivy-mode`, so that explains this difference.

Comment: Hmm, well, isn't this a question for http://emacs.stackexchange.com/, then?